# What is the relevance of this statement in 7.1.6.1/1 in the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, language-lawyer, volatile

7.1.6.1/1 contains the following statement (emphasis mine):

> There are two *cv-qualifiers*, const and volatile. **If a *cv-qualifier*
>   appears in a *decl-specifier-seq*, the *init-declarator-list* of the
>   declaration shall not be empty**.

What is the relevance of the statement in bold above? In other words, is it possible to produce an example of a **cv-unqualified**  type in a *decl-specifier-seq*, in which the *init-declarator-list* of the declaration is empty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, most class and enum definitions make use of it:

```
struct A { }; // valid
const struct B { }; // invalid, const would have no meaning
const struct C { } c { }; // valid
```

There is nothing else. An init-declarator-list is only used in a simple-declaration, and for that, the standard (C++11) states:

> **7 Declarations [dcl.dcl]**
>
> 3 In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*.

Comment: I was too quick with my answer - however, can you come up with anything else? I'm struggling.

Comment: I don't think there is anything else. Actually, I don't think this says anything about implicit int either. Function parameter declarations don't have any init-declarator-list, and if they did, your answer would suggest that `void f(const int);` is an invalid declaration.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I deleted my answer, I only became aware of those facts later. :)

Comment: Yeah, and that's why it isn't interesting - it's the exact same pattern. Wouldn't hurt if you included that though.

Comment: @hvd But the valid examples you gave are already covered by 7/3. What's then the need of the above mentioned statement in 7.1.6.1/1?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil There is nothing else prohibiting `const struct B { };`. 7p3 would have allowed `const struct B { };`: it is a simple-declaration declaring a class.

Comment: @hvd I have to disagree. 7/3 mentions a class-specifier, an elaborated-type-specifier with a class-key, or an enum-specifier. None of them include a cv-qualifier.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil It says "contains" a class-specifier, which `const struct B { };` certainly does: it's a cv-qualifier followed by a class-specifier. If you disagree, how would you parse it?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but I don't agree with your interpretation of the word "contains" in the context of 7/3. Thanks.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil FWIW, most compilers do agree with my interpretation: `typedef struct S { };` is valid, is accepted, and the `typedef` keyword is simply ignored. If I understand you correctly, you say that since `typedef` is part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, since the *decl-specifier-seq* contains more than merely a *class-specifier*, it should be an error. GCC and Intel accept it with only a warning in modes where they turn any standard-mandated diagnostic into a hard error. clang does appear to agree with you, though, so perhaps it's not as clear as I thought it is.

Comment: @hvd `clang does appear to agree with you, though, so perhaps it's not as clear as I thought it is` - clang is the one that ignores the `typedef` accepting the declaration, GCC doesn't. So I would say that I agree with GCC. I'm convinced that the statement highlighted in 7.1.6.1/1 is superfluous, as 7.3 takes care of the problem alluded in 7.1.6.1/1.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil clang is the one that makes it an error with `-pedantic-errors`, gcc and Intel are the ones that leave it as a warning in that mode. :)

Comment: @hvd You're correct. My experience with GCC and clang boils down to web compilers like Coliru. I was just using -pedantic and now, it seems to me both compile the code ignoring the typedef. With -errors GCC ignores the typedef and clang produces an error. Could you tell me what is the difference between -pedantic and -pedantic-errors?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil If a construct is invalid C or C++ but normally silently ignored, and the standard requires a diagnostic, then `-pedantic` turns that into a warning, and `-pedantic-errors` into an error. Example: `int main() { return 0LL; }` in C90 mode. If a construct is invalid C or C++ and normally warned about, `-pedantic` keeps it at a warning, but `-pedantic-errors` turns it into an error. Example: `int *i = "abc";`. If a construct is valid C or C++, neither `-pedantic` nor `-pedantic-errors` has any effect on any warnings you get for it, even if the warnings are enabled by default.